# In React Js I want to try to open modal after clicking on card but the modal is not open after clicking on card

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Please help me to sort out this problem I want to open modal after clicking n card. I have use button and under that, I use card.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
    import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import CardDesing from './CardDesing'
    import Modals from './Modal';


    class App extends React.Component {

        render() {
            return (

                <Button onClick={this.onCardClick} className="unstyled-button">
                    <CardDesing /> 
                </Button>

            );
        }

        onCardClick = () => {
            console.log("hello");
            return (
                <Modals />
            );
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"))
```

Comment: In general, assume event handlers will not expect a return value. If you think through this example, how would `onClick` know that it should treat its return value as JSX? and if it did know somehow, where should it be rendered?

Comment: There are already answers describing how to fix it. Just trying to explain why the current code doesn't make sense logically, so that you can understand how their answers work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render your model conditionally. if button is clicked then we are showing model

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import CardDesing from './CardDesing'
import Modals from './Modal';

class App extends React.Component {

    state = {
      isClicked : false // button clicked or not 
    }

   // set new state to your isClicked
   onCardClick = () => {
       this.setState({ isClicked : !this.state.isClicked }) 
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <>
            <Button onClick={this.onCardClick} className="unstyled-button">
                <CardDesing /> 
            </Button>
            {
                this.state.isClicked ?   <Modals /> : '' 
            }
         </>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"))
```

Comment: let me know if you have any query.

Answer (score 0):

Render modal and just show it on click:

```
state = {
  show: false
}
render() {
  return (
    <>
     <Button onClick={this.onCardClick} className="unstyled-button">
        <CardDesing /> 
     </Button>
     { this.state.show && <Modals /> || '' }
   </>
  );
}

onCardClick = () => {
  this.setState({ show: true })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [react-bootstrap docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/)

You should use the property: `show`: When true The modal will show itself.

Example:

```
function Example() {
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const handleClose = () => setShow(false);
    const handleShow = () => setShow(true);

    return (
        <div>
            <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleShow}>
                Launch demo modal
            </Button>

            <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
                {/*  */}
            </Modal>
        </div>
    );
}
```